# Basic Umbraco back-end section project structure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, umbraco, umbraco7

I have developed a new section for my Umbraco site (a back-end section). It includes a nav item, tree view and functionality etc.

Is it possible to isolate this into one project? i.e. for each Umbraco section have a project in Visual Studio with all of the relevant Umbraco references? If so, how can I then add this project to the 'main' web project in a way that, when doing so, would deploy the section?

Comment: In a word, yes.

In more words - install the UmbracoCMS.Core nuget package in your custom section project, then just include the compiled project dll into your Umbraco installation along with whatever necessary javascript etc. files (~/App_Plugins/etc.)

Comment: As an aside, you could package up your custom project as a nuget package itself including all the content files etc., install that into your Umbraco project and that way release it as a plugin if you wanted to.